# SVG `viewBox` removed in production build but kept in dev mode (using Parcel bundler)

Tags: svg, vue.js, parceljs

Why does the Parcel production build of this basic Vue.js app remove the hardcoded `viewBox` attribute on the SVG icon? In local development mode, `viewBox` is not removed and the svg renders correctly.

Here is the production build with the problem svg, live on netlify: https://errands.netlify.com/.

Here is a screenshot of the production build (missing the gray "edit" icons to the left of each grocery item name):

[image: production build missing each list item svg viewBox attribute]

And here is a screenshot of the svg rendered correctly in dev mode (see the gray "edit" icon to the left of each grocery item name):

[image: local dev build with the svg viewBox attribute as exptected]

Here is the source for the svg as a Vue component: https://github.com/brianzelip/groceries-vue/blob/master/src/components/Icons/IconEditSolid.vue

Here’s the parent component that calls the above svg component: https://github.com/brianzelip/groceries-vue/blob/master/src/components/GroceryForm/GroceryFormItemEditLink.vue

**Why does the production build remove the `viewBox` attribute on svg elements? And how to stop that behavior?**

Comment: You could test if there is a dependency to [svgo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svgo) somewhere (`npm ls svgo`) and find out if you can either configure or remove it. (Personal rant: While svgo claims to "optimize" svgs, in my experience it tends to remove superfluous and essential attributes in equal parts.)

Comment: From [this](https://github.com/posthtml/htmlnano/issues/53) it seems you can add a `.htmlnanorc` file and set `{ "minifySvg": false }`.